# FICO score calculation exact breakdown

Tags: united-states, credit-report

Do I have any legal ground to demand an exact breakdown of my FICO score? The precise formula and data points that were used for my report, not some generic explanation.

Comment: The FICO formula is proprietary they do not reveal it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

It's a trade secret owned by FICO, formerly Fair, Isaac and Company (1956-2003) and Fair Isaac Corporation (2003-2009). As a [trade secret](https://www.uspto.gov/ip-policy/trade-secret-policy), it is protected and breaches of the secrecy carry criminal and civil punishments.

Btw: Releasing the formula would invalidate all scores based on it, as it would open doors to manipulate the own score.